# How are population fractions and sampling fractions derived?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I have this function:

```
corrected_prob<- function(result,population_fraction,sample_fraction){
value<-1/(1+(1/population_fraction-1)/(1/sample_fraction-1)*(1/result-1))
return(value)
}
```

Which I then use population_fraction and sample_fraction on it:

```
yprob_corrected <- corrected_prob(result=y_prob, population_fraction =0.04, sample_fraction =0.33)
```

In statistics, how does one derive population fraction and sample fractions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your definitions or why you feel 'correction'
is needed.

**Population.** If a random variable $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 10, p = .4),$ then $P(X = 5)$ is the long run proportion of occurrences of the result `5` when the binomial experiment described by this model is performed. Specifically, $$P(X = 5) = {10 \choose 5}(.4)^5(.6)^5 = 0.2006581,$$ which can be computed in R as follows:

```
dbinom(5, 10, .4)
[1] 0.2006581
```

**Samples.** If the binomial experiment is repeated many times, say $10\,000,$ the number of occurrences of `5` divided by $10\,000$ is the population proportion of `5`s. The Law of Large Numbers
says that this sample proportion becomes closer to the probability 0.2006581 as the number of repetitions increases.
So for $10\,000$ repetitions, we can expect a pretty good match. The program below shows one of many ways to simulate
$10\,000$ repetitions.

```
set.seed(1028)  # for reproducibility
x = rbinom(10000, 10, .4)
table(x)
x
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 
  60  424 1200 2170 2461 2014 1099  453   99   20
```

So we say $2014$ occurrences of `5` in $10\,000$ iterations,
for a sample proportion of $0.2014.$ As expected, this is
close to the population proportion, but not an exact match.
I know of no legitimate way to 'correct' 0.2014 to get closer
to 0.2006581. (Starting over with a larger number of iterations might get a sample proportion closer to 0.2006581; but that's a re-enactment not a 'correction'.)

**Graphical comparison.** The histogram below shows the number of occurrences of the
numbers 0 through 10 from the simulation experiment. The centers
of the red circles show the exact binomial probabilities.
The match is good for `5`'s, and also for the other possible values.

[image]

If this is not what you meant by your question, please try to
be specific why not, and please try to give an example of your own to explain what kind of help you're looking for.

Comment: I don't know how the 0.04 and 0.33, population fraction and sample fraction respectively, were derived at. There's no explanation on it. So, I am curious to know how these are generally derived at statistically. It would seem that your 0.2006581 might be pointing to part of it. However, its not clear to me where the 5, 10 and 0.4 came from.

Comment: It's an _example:_ Suppose $0.4 = 40\%$ of population has had some post-secondary education. You select 10 people at random. What is the probability exactly 5 of them have some such education? Answer is 0.2006581 (just a bit more than 20%). That's a fact about a population. // Now suppose you repeat this expt 10000 times. What proportion of the 10000 samples of 10 will have exactly 5? Simulated this experiment. Got 2014 out of 10,000 samples of 10 with exactly 5. That's 2014/10000 (a little mre than 20%). That's based on data. ...

Comment: Before you start writing R functions (much less asking other people to puzzle them out without any in-line comments, explanation, or documentation), you must have definitions and a concept clearly in mind--and be able to explain what you are trying to do and why.  //  I think you may need to go back to review and ponder definitions of 'population', 'sample', 'probability', etc. //Alan Turing once said it is possible to write computer code in such a way no one would be able to figure out the purpose of it. He had machine language with 0's and 1's in mind, I think. But that also goes for R code.